# Why are all the Razor Views in my app caching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC 3 application where I am using razor views.  I have a SiteLayout.cshtml page, which is my master page for the site.  Then, I have a Login.cshtml page which uses the SiteLayout.cshtml as the master page.  I also have a _ViewStart.cshtml page that applies the master page to all cshtml pages.

I recently added a 'Forgot password' link to my login page.  When I run the app, it doesn't show the new link.  I cleaned the solution & rebuilt the solution, but that didn't help.  Its almost like the razor views are getting cached.  I checked all my browser settings (IE, Firefox, Chrome) to make sure that they are not caching.

I am totally stumped with this one.  Any ideas??

Here is the code for the master page:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Application - @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/Content/Site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Total width: 1180px -->
    <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="header">
            <span style="text-align:left; float:left;">Header</span>
            <span style="text-align:right; float:right; width:200px;">@Html.Partial("LoginStatus")</span>
        </div>
        <div id="maincontent">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</Html>
```

Code for the login view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
<div style="width:500px;">
@using(Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="errorMessage">@Html.ValidationMessage("LoginError")</div>
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Email", string.Empty, new { @style = "width:250px;" })
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        @Html.Password("Password", string.Empty, new { @style = "width:100px;" }) <br/><br />
        <div class="buttons">
            <button type="submit" class="positive" name="login">
                <img src="/Content/images/lock_open.png" alt=""/>
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password?", "ForgotPassword", "Account")</p>
    </fieldset>
}
</div>
```

Finally, code for _ViewStart:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Here's something else, I published the website to IIS & it displays the correct version of the view.  So why would IIS show the correct view and the in-build dev server not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it figured out.  I am sure it has something to do with the configuration of my machine since its not happening to others.  So, instead of allowing VS2010 to assign its own port, I forced-picked a port.  And I now get the new view.

Answer (score 2):

Hit [control] + F5 to force a refresh.

Above each Action method you can set an output caching attribute for that page.  Here is an article on it [output caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)

Alternatively you can set your caching preferences site wide in the web.config

Comment: I used the following setting in the config to turn off the caching without any luck.

<caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
</caching>

Comment: did you try hitting control and f5 several times

Comment: Maybe try moving the link to above the text boxes.  Maybe CSS is hiding it.  If you do ViewSource from the browser, does it show up in the source?  Finally, i would try to use a standard <a> tag instead of the helper.

Comment: I tried that too.  Its almost like the development web server is somehow caching the output.  The view that I see and the view that I have complied are several versions apart.

Answer (score 0):

Besides cleaning and rebuilding, which you mentioned you had done, You might want to check and make sure you don't have any instances of your .NET Development server running.

If you don't want caching to occur at all, you can use the following attribute to ensure that nothing is cached:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
//Your Controller Here
```

Comment: I tried this but the view is still getting cached.  I also made sure that there weren't any additional instances of the .net web server running.  This is most peculiar.

Comment: That is bizarre - you could try putting the [OutputCache] attribute over the method that is calling that View? Is it being loaded traditionally or is it a partial view, perhaps being loaded through AJAX?

Comment: I have updated my orig post & added html from the views.  I am using the @renderbody method to automatically render the contents of the login view into the master page.